# How to combine TaskT with the monad instance of Trampoline to get stackless async computations?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers, trampolines

`Trampoline` is a monad and adds stack-safety to a monad transformer stack. It achieves this by relying on a special interpreter (`monadRec`), which is fed with the result of a monadic computation (actually it is a specialized version of the free monad pattern). For this reason the `Trampoline` monad must be the outermost monad, that is the base monad of the transformer stack.

In the following setting `TaskT` (which is essentially `Cont` with sharing) is the monad transformer and `Trampoline` the base monad:

```js
// TASK

const TaskT = taskt => record(
  TaskT,
  thisify(o => {
    o.taskt = k =>
      taskt(x => {
        o.taskt = k_ => k_(x);
        return k(x);
      });

    return o;
  }));

// Monad

const taskChainT = mmx => fmm =>
  TaskT(k =>
    mmx.taskt(x =>
      fmm(x).taskt(k)));

const taskOfT = x =>
  TaskT(k => k(x));

// Transformer

const taskLiftT = chain => mmx =>
  TaskT(k => chain(mmx) (k));

// auxiliary functions

const taskAndT = mmx => mmy =>
  taskChainT(mmx) (x =>
    taskChainT(mmy) (y =>
      taskOfT([x, y])));

const delayTaskT = f => ms => x =>
  TaskT(k => setTimeout(comp(k) (f), ms, x));

const record = (type, o) => (
  o[Symbol.toStringTag] = type.name || type, o);

const thisify = f => f({});

const log = (...ss) =>
  (console.log(...ss), ss[ss.length - 1]);

// TRAMPOLINE

const monadRec = o => {
  while (o.tag === "Chain")
    o = o.fm(o.chain);

  return o.tag === "Of"
    ? o.of
    : _throw(new TypeError("unknown trampoline tag"));
};

// tags

const Chain = chain => fm =>
  ({tag: "Chain", fm, chain});


const Of = of =>
  ({tag: "Of", of});

// Monad

const recOf = Of;

const recChain = mx => fm =>
  mx.tag === "Chain" ? Chain(mx.chain) (x => recChain(mx.fm(x)) (fm))
    : mx.tag === "Of" ? fm(mx.of)
    : _throw(new TypeError("unknown trampoline tag"));

// MAIN

const foo = x =>
  Chain(delayTaskT(x => x) (0) (x)) (Of);

const bar = taskAndT(
  taskLiftT(recChain) (foo(1)))
    (taskLiftT(recChain) (foo(2))); // yields TaskT

const main = bar.taskt(x => Of(log(x))); // yields Chain({fm, chain: TaskT})

monadRec(main); // yields [TaskT, TaskT] but [1, 2] desired
```

This is not what I want, because the `Trampoline` forces evaluation before the event loop receives the result of the asynchronous tasks. What I need is the other way around but as I've already mentioned there is no `TrampolineT` transformer. What am I missing?

Comment: short answer from below: use `taskLiftT(recChain) (Of(1)))` instead of `taskLiftT(recChain) (foo(1)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in this code snippet.

#### Issue #1: There is no monad transformer for `IO` (i.e. `Task`)

It's well known that there is no monad transformer for `IO`.<sup>[1]</sup> Your `TaskT` type is modeled after `ContT`, and `ContT` is indeed a monad transformer. However, you're using `TaskT` to perform asynchronous computations such as `setTimeout`, which is where the problem arises.

Consider the definition of `TaskT`, which is similar to `ContT`.

```hs
newtype TaskT r m a = TaskT { taskt :: (a -> m r) -> m r }
```

Hence, `delayTaskT` should have the type `(a -> b) -> Number -> a -> TaskT r m b`.

```js
const delayTaskT = f => ms => x =>
  TaskT(k => setTimeout(comp(k) (f), ms, x));
```

However, `setTimeout(comp(k) (f), ms, x)` returns a timeout id which does not match the type `m r`. Note that `k => setTimeout(comp(k) (f), ms, x)` should have the type `(b -> m r) -> m r`.

In fact, it's impossible to conjure a value of type `m r` when the continuation `k` is called asynchronously. The `ContT` monad transformer only works for synchronous computations.

Nevertheless, we can define `Task` as a specialized version of `Cont`.

```hs
newtype Task a = Task { task :: (a -> ()) -> () } -- Task = Cont ()
```

Thus, whenever `Task` is present in a monad transformer stack it'll always be at the base, just like `IO`.

If you want to make the `Task` monad stack safe then read the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57307531/783743).

#### Issue #2: The `foo` function has the wrong return type

Let's assume for a moment that `delayTaskT` has the correct type. The next issue, as you have already noticed is that `foo` has the wrong return type.

> The problem seems to be `foo` which return a `TaskT` wrapped in a `Chain` and this wrapped `TaskT` is completely decoupled from the `TaskT` chain and is thus never evaluated/fired.

I'm assuming that the expected type of `foo` is `a -> TaskT r Trampoline a`. However, the actual type of `foo` is `a -> Trampoline (TaskT r m a)`. Fortunately, the fix is easy.

```js
const foo = delayTaskT(x => x) (0);
```

The type of `foo` is the same as `taskOfT`, i.e. `a -> TaskT r m a`. We can specialize `m = Trampoline`.

#### Issue #3: You're not using `taskLiftT` correctly

The `taskLiftT` function lifts an underlying monadic computation into the `TaskT` layer.

```hs
taskLiftT :: (forall a b. m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b) -> m a -> TaskT r m a

taskLiftT(recChain) :: Trampoline a -> TaskT r Trampoline a
```

Now, you're applying `taskLiftT(recChain)` to `foo(1)` and `foo(2)`.

```hs
foo :: a -> Trampoline (TaskT r m a) -- incorrect definition of foo

foo(1) :: Trampoline (TaskT r m Number)
foo(2) :: Trampoline (TaskT r m Number)

taskLiftT(recChain) (foo(1)) :: TaskT r Trampoline (TaskT r m Number)
taskLiftT(recChain) (foo(2)) :: TaskT r Trampoline (TaskT r m Number)
```

However, if we use the correct definition of `foo` then the types wouldn't even match.

```hs
foo :: a -> TaskT r Trampoline a -- correct definition of foo

foo(1) :: TaskT r Trampoline Number
foo(2) :: TaskT r Trampoline Number

-- Can't apply taskLiftT(recChain) to foo(1) or foo(2)
```

If we're using the correct definition of `foo` then there are two ways to define `bar`. Note that there's no way to correctly define `foo` using `setTimeout`. Hence, I have redefined `foo` as `taskOfT`.

1. Use `foo` and don't use `taskLiftT`.

   ```js
   const bar = taskAndT(foo(1))(foo(2)); // yields TaskT
   ```

   ```js
   // TASK

   const TaskT = taskt => record(
     TaskT,
     thisify(o => {
       o.taskt = k =>
         taskt(x => {
           o.taskt = k_ => k_(x);
           return k(x);
         });

       return o;
     }));

   // Monad

   const taskChainT = mmx => fmm =>
     TaskT(k =>
       mmx.taskt(x =>
         fmm(x).taskt(k)));

   const taskOfT = x =>
     TaskT(k => k(x));

   // Transformer

   const taskLiftT = chain => mmx =>
     TaskT(k => chain(mmx) (k));

   // auxiliary functions

   const taskAndT = mmx => mmy =>
     taskChainT(mmx) (x =>
       taskChainT(mmy) (y =>
         taskOfT([x, y])));

   const delayTaskT = f => ms => x =>
     TaskT(k => setTimeout(comp(k) (f), ms, x));

   const record = (type, o) => (
     o[Symbol.toStringTag] = type.name || type, o);

   const thisify = f => f({});

   const log = (...ss) =>
     (console.log(...ss), ss[ss.length - 1]);

   // TRAMPOLINE

   const monadRec = o => {
     while (o.tag === "Chain")
       o = o.fm(o.chain);

     return o.tag === "Of"
       ? o.of
       : _throw(new TypeError("unknown trampoline tag"));
   };

   // tags

   const Chain = chain => fm =>
     ({tag: "Chain", fm, chain});


   const Of = of =>
     ({tag: "Of", of});

   // Monad

   const recOf = Of;

   const recChain = mx => fm =>
     mx.tag === "Chain" ? Chain(mx.chain) (x => recChain(mx.fm(x)) (fm))
       : mx.tag === "Of" ? fm(mx.of)
       : _throw(new TypeError("unknown trampoline tag"));

   // MAIN

   const foo = taskOfT;

   const bar = taskAndT(foo(1))(foo(2)); // yields TaskT

   const main = bar.taskt(x => Of(log(x))); // yields Chain({fm, chain: TaskT})

   monadRec(main); // yields [TaskT, TaskT] but [1, 2] desired
   ```
2. Don't use `foo` and use `taskLiftT`.

   ```js
   const bar = taskAndT(
     taskLiftT(recChain) (Of(1)))
       (taskLiftT(recChain) (Of(2))); // yields TaskT
   ```

   ```js
   // TASK

   const TaskT = taskt => record(
     TaskT,
     thisify(o => {
       o.taskt = k =>
         taskt(x => {
           o.taskt = k_ => k_(x);
           return k(x);
         });

       return o;
     }));

   // Monad

   const taskChainT = mmx => fmm =>
     TaskT(k =>
       mmx.taskt(x =>
         fmm(x).taskt(k)));

   const taskOfT = x =>
     TaskT(k => k(x));

   // Transformer

   const taskLiftT = chain => mmx =>
     TaskT(k => chain(mmx) (k));

   // auxiliary functions

   const taskAndT = mmx => mmy =>
     taskChainT(mmx) (x =>
       taskChainT(mmy) (y =>
         taskOfT([x, y])));

   const delayTaskT = f => ms => x =>
     TaskT(k => setTimeout(comp(k) (f), ms, x));

   const record = (type, o) => (
     o[Symbol.toStringTag] = type.name || type, o);

   const thisify = f => f({});

   const log = (...ss) =>
     (console.log(...ss), ss[ss.length - 1]);

   // TRAMPOLINE

   const monadRec = o => {
     while (o.tag === "Chain")
       o = o.fm(o.chain);

     return o.tag === "Of"
       ? o.of
       : _throw(new TypeError("unknown trampoline tag"));
   };

   // tags

   const Chain = chain => fm =>
     ({tag: "Chain", fm, chain});


   const Of = of =>
     ({tag: "Of", of});

   // Monad

   const recOf = Of;

   const recChain = mx => fm =>
     mx.tag === "Chain" ? Chain(mx.chain) (x => recChain(mx.fm(x)) (fm))
       : mx.tag === "Of" ? fm(mx.of)
       : _throw(new TypeError("unknown trampoline tag"));

   // MAIN

   const foo = taskOfT;

   const bar = taskAndT(
     taskLiftT(recChain) (Of(1)))
       (taskLiftT(recChain) (Of(2))); // yields TaskT

   const main = bar.taskt(x => Of(log(x))); // yields Chain({fm, chain: TaskT})

   monadRec(main); // yields [TaskT, TaskT] but [1, 2] desired
   ```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> [Why is there no IO transformer in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13056663/783743)

Comment: The connection between the opaque `IO` type and asynchonicity was the missing link. The defunctionalization along with trampolining you demonstrate in the linked answer introduces a lot of complexity but is still very helpful. I think I will also explore the interpreter (specialized free monad) approach and see whether lazyness could be helpful to gain stack safety. I will accept your answer as soon as I can award a bounty. Thank you!